# Ruby date parsing

Tags: ruby, date

I'm sure I'm missing something obvious, but - I'm trying to parse a date like "8/5/2018" (in m/d/y format).  Ruby seems perfectly capable of creating dates in this format using the format string `%-m/%-d/%Y` and `strftime`, but for some reason `strptime` can't read it?

```
[1] pry(main)> require 'date'
=> true
[2] pry(main)> format = '%-m/%-d/%Y'
=> "%-m/%-d/%Y"
[3] pry(main)> today = Date.today.strftime(format)
=> "8/5/2018"
[4] pry(main)> Date.strptime(today, format)
ArgumentError: invalid date
from (pry):4:in `strptime'
```

Does `strptime` use a different set of format keys than `strftime` (the ruby docs seem to suggest that they're the same)?  Or am I missing something else here?

Answer (score 3):

They use the same format keys, but the docs for [`strptime`](https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib/libdoc/date/rdoc/Date.html#method-c-strptime) state:

> strptime does not support specification of flags and width unlike strftime.

So the issue is those flags (in this case the hyphens (-). Kind of dumb that you can't just use the same format specifier for inputting dates, as well as outputting them, but it is what it is, you could do:

```
Date.strptime(today, format.delete('-'))
```

Answer (score 0):

the problem is about format! if you change it to

> %m/%d/%Y

, it will be fix !

```
format = '%m/%d/%Y'
today = Date.today.strftime(format)
Date.strptime(today, format)
#=> Mon, 06 Aug 2018
```